# How to succinctly get the first 5 characters of a string in swift?

Tags: swift

What is the most succinct way to get the first 5 characters of a String in swift? Thank you.

Answer (score 41):

**First 5 chars**

```
let str = "SampleText"
let result = String(str.characters.prefix(5)) // result = "Sampl"
```

**SWIFT 4**

```
let str = "SampleText"
let result = String(str.prefix(5)) // result = "Sampl"
```

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4 it changed:

```
let text         = "sampleText"

let resultPrefix = text.prefix(5)  //result = "sampl"
let resultSuffix = text.suffix(6) // result = "eText"
```

Comment: Only 5 chars for suffix(6)?

Comment: Yes last 5 chars.

Answer (score 1):

Get the index upto 5 character and then use substring

```
let str = "Hello World!"
if str.utf16.count >= 5{
    let a = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 5)
    let result = str.substring(to: a)
}else{
    //lenght in shorter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5,

```
let str:String = "Sam Fisher"
let result = str.prefix(3) //You get 'sam'
```